# Appending values into a list with except: pass

Tags: python, list, debugging, encryption, binary

```
for c in update:
    try:
        converted = (int(c,2))
        check = chr(converted)
        #Converts the inverted list back into a character
    except:
        overflow.append(c)
        check = None
        pass
    encrypt.append(check)
```

What happens is that I take a string switch it into binary, invert the binary. For example 1101 turns into 0010, then attempt to switch it back into string.

Of course, Windows does not have mappings for invalid binaries, so I'm making `overflow` (a list) for the invalids. I am having trouble appending values onto that list.

[Here is when I try a different method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNNAv.png)

Different method code:

```
for c in update:
    converted = (int(c,2))
    check = chr(converted)
    if check=="�":
        overflow.append(c)
    #Converts the inverted list back into a character
    #overflow.append(c)
    encrypt_list.append(check)
```

Comment: What us your error? What happens when and invalid binary occurs.

Comment: There is no error, it is just the fact that I am not able to append "c", when the try statement fails.